# Is "synchronize X with someone" idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Is "synchronize X with someone" idiomatic? I am not sure how idiomatic it is, because this phrase is not seen often, but I feel it might be possibly correct, because semantically it seems to be correct.

For example:

> You were trying to **synchronize your jumps with your wife** during the
>   race.

Saying wife's instead of wife looks weird. Am I wrong to say that?

Comment: Do you mean *your jumps with your* ***wife's***?

Comment: Is there a better way to say it?

Comment: What do you mean by jumps

Comment: jump as in jumping

Comment: @blackbird *Synchronizing your jumps with your* ***wife*** doesn't make any sense. What exactly do you mean by that? If you change it to *wife's*, then your jumps are synchronized with her jumps. But if it's not her *jumps* that you synchronize with, what is it? It might also work if you remove *your*, and just say *you are trying to synchronize jumps with your wife*. In that form, it's clear that it's *your jumps* and *your wife's jumps* that are being synchronized—even if it's not clearly spelled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choices are:

> 1. You were trying to synchronize **your** jumps with your **wife's jumps** during the race.

or

> 2. You were trying to synchronize **your** jumps with your **wife's** during the race.

or

> 3. You were trying to synchronize jumps with your wife during the race.

---

regarding:

> Saying wife's instead of wife looks weird. Am I wrong to say that?

Saying "wife's" is case #2, where you are implying the word "jumps", but omitting it. This usage is not weird. If you prefer to say "wife", then case #3.